# Warning when adding user control to window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working with a tab control in my window, and my code looks something like this:

```
<TabControl>

    <TabItem Header="Clock">
        ...
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Stopwatch">
        <Controls:Stopwatch/>
    </TabItem>

</TabControl>
```

Whenever I added the user control (`<Controls:StopWatch/>`) the designer restarted and started giving me error: `Project code has been disabled to improve the designer stability`

**[Stopwatch.xaml & Stopwatch.xaml.cs](https://gist.github.com/NerijusPocevicius/e0ce6f13c416033022bb299b385b3261)**

**Note:** the stopwatch.xaml designer doesn't give any errors, works fluently.
**Note:** whenever I commented the user control, the designer started working fluently in my window. So the error is in the user control.

Is there a way to fix this problem, and I would like to get an answer why this is happening.

Comment: your `Stopwatch` is causing problems with designer... Cannot help you without it's code

Comment: What does `StopWatch` do? Clearly the designer has some issue with it. When you are using the designer *it is running your code*. So if you code does something that, for example, is really slow, or depends on something not available at design time it can break the designer. You may need to make `StopWatch` aware of whether or not it's in design mode